# Windows 2003 Server Static IP resets to DHCP on reboot

Tags: windows-server-2003, ip, static-ip

I have a customer who has a Dell Server running Win 2003 R2 Server.
This is an existing machine that we had setup with a static IP.  Now they want to change it to  another static IP.

When they go and change it, hit ok, then reboot.  The config is back to the old IP #.

The user is the administrator.

My guess is it has to do with AD & GP, a virus, an already in use IP#, or something else?

Anyone have any ideas what else could cause this behavior?

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged with DHCP, it sounds like both addresses in question are static. Did I miss something?

Comment: Most servers have at least 2 NICs, are they definitely setting the new address on the right one?

Comment: I had tagged it DHCP by mistake, cann't remove it now

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on a Dell PowerEdge 1950 with Broadcom NIC's installed. Running "netsh reset int ip" from a command line fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work after changing the IP, before rebooting?  Rebooting is not required to change an IP address.

Is there any anti-virus or security software that may be overzealous in protecting network settings?

Answer (score 0):

Broadcom NICs? Its a known issue. I can't remember the solution exactly, but if you call Dell support, they should be able to help you in a few minutes.

Basically this is due to a package not installed properly during Dell automated install (or maybe vice versa - you HAVE to use the OMSA CD to install the OS)

Just call support - it's a well documented issue, easy to solve

Comment: still looking in to this.  Our user is going through upgrading their nics.  We'll see if that helps at all, then I'll mark this as answered.
Thank you

Comment: This is why we don't use the broadcom NICs, we always get Intel NIC cards to save us any trouble.

Comment: Hondalex, b-coms are OK when you know their quirks, and this issue has been around for years now - there's an easy and well documented solution available, only one support call to Dell away