# Static IP settings on Windows 2003 server not getting saved

Tags: windows-server-2003, static-ip, dell-poweredge

We have a Dell PowerEgde 1950 server with Broadcom NetXtreme gigabit ethernet card, and we are facing a strange problem with static IP assignment. When we assign a static IP to this broadcom NIC, settings are not getting saved.

Following are the steps to reproduce problem

- open TCP/IP properties window for broadcom NIC
- manually enter static IP address and other details like gateway, DNS, etc.
- apply and close properties dialog.
- re-open TCP/IP properties windows, you will see your static IP settings lost and changed to "obtain IP address manually"
- but when checked using ipconfig command, you will still see your same static IP settings
- but, when checked using ipconfig command after rebooting server, these static ip settings are completely gone and automatically obtained IP is assigned

**Supplementary information**: Recently we had formatted this server and installed windows 2003 from OEM windows setup CD (not from OS installation CD received from Dell). After windows installation was over, broadcom NIC drivers were installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with Broadcom NIC drivers. This is the reason why network admins generally prefers Intel NICs over Broadcom. Following is the detailed procedure to solve this issue (Note that I have verified this procedure only Dell PE 1950, but it may work for other familities of Dell PE as well)-

***NIC loses Static IP Configuration***

What to do:

```
   a.    Uninstall old Broadcom Advanced Control Suite. 

   b.    Clean the system of older Broadcom file versions. 

   c.    Reinstall the Broadcom Drivers.
```

How to do it:

a.       Download the new Broadcom drivers

```
    i.      32-bit http://ftp.us.dell.com/network/Bcom_LAN_12.4_W2K3_8_A02.exe 

    ii.     64-bit http://ftp.us.dell.com/network/Bcom_LAN_12.4_W2K3_8_64_A03.exe
```

Important!

For Server 2008, leave all .Net Framework Versions in place, continue at step D.

b.      Ensure Microsoft’s .Net Framework 2.0 SP1 is installed.

c.       Install .Net Framework 2.0 SP1 from Microsoft.

d.      Ensure .Net Framework 2.0 SP2, 3.0 and 3.5 are NOT installed.  They can be reinstalled after installing the new Broadcom drivers.

e.      Disable/Pause any Antivirus and Threat-Protection scanners that can interrupt the Broadcom driver installation.

```
     i.         Check for Symantec Endpoint. 

     ii.       If it is installed, ensure Endpoint Patch RM4 (or newer) is installed. 

     iii.      If RM4 (or newer) cannot be installed, then uninstall Endpoint. Endpoint may be re-installed later.
```

f.        Extract BCOMRemove.zip

g.    Rename the following files:

```
    i.         BCOM_Remove.txt  -> BCOM_Remove.vbs 
    ii.       BCOM_Finalize.txt -> BCOM_Finalize.vbs
```

h.      Uninstall the existing Broadcom drivers through Add/Remove Programs.

i.         Select No for restart now

j.        Uninstall all Broadcom NICs and BASFND from Device Manager.

```
   i.         Click Start -> Run -> Type CMD. 

   ii.       Type set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1. 

   iii.      Type Start DEVMGMT.MSC. 

   iv.     Click View. 

   v.       Click Show Hidden Devices. 

   vi.     Expand the Network Adapters section on the left. 

   vii.    Remove all listed Broadcom network adapters. 
            1.      Right-click the network adapter 
            2.      Click Uninstall. 

   viii.  Expand the Non-Plug and Play Drivers section on the left. 

   ix.     Remove all instances of BASFND 

   x.       Expand the System devices section on the left. 

   xi.     Remove all instances of BASFND 

   xii.    Remove all listed Broadcom network adapters. 
          1.      Right-click the network adapter 
          2.      Click Uninstall
```

k.       Double-Click BCOM_Remove.vbs

l.         Reboot

m.    Enable NICs in BIOS.

n.      Cancel the Found new hardware wizard

o.      Double-click BCOM_Finalize.vbs

p.    Install the Broadcom Drivers

```
    i.         Double-click the Broadcom installer to extract the files to C:\Broadcom\w2k3_8. 

            1.      32-bit:   Bcom_LAN_12.4_W2K3_8_A02.exe 
            2.      64-bit:   Bcom_LAN_12.4_W2K3_8_64_A03.exe 

    ii.       Navigate to C:\Broadcom\w2k3_8\Driver_Management_Apps_Installer 

    iii.      Double-Click Setup.Exe. 

    iv.     Follow the installation wizard to complete the installation.
```

q.      For Domain Controllers, follow Microsoft KB article 325356 (How to remove and reinstall TCP/IP on a Windows Server 2003 domain controller)

r.        For Non-Domain Controllers, follow Microsoft KB article 317518. (How to reset "Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)" in Windows Server 2003)

s.        netsh interface ip reset resetlog.txt

Answer (score 0):

A similar (if not identical issue) is detailed here.

[Windows 2003 Server Static IP resets to DHCP on reboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/63530/windows-2003-server-static-ip-resets-to-dhcp-on-reboot)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an entry in the registry does not get removed when uninstalling the Broadcom drivers. You can remove the entry and reset the static IP to resolve the issue. I spoke with Dell regarding this and they sent me the process.

1. Open RegEdit
2. Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network
3. Delete the Config Key and click Yes to confirm the delete
4. Open the Network Connections
5. Right-click on the Local Area Connection and select Properties
6. If you're still set for Obtain an IP automatically, set it to the IP it should be. otherwise, click OK to close the properties.
7. Click OK.

You shouldn't need a reboot, but my server did. The link below has you remove a few other registry entries but I didn't. It also has you remove the drivers for the NIC but if you have the latest drivers it may not me necessary. The steps above were all that I did and the problem was resolved.

For more information, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937056